# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I'm new to stackoverflow, and don't know much about the rules. Just a few minutes ago, one of the moderators deleted my answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581596/printing-dynamic-dom-data-in-console-log/34582477#34582477), after it was accepted by the question asker. I read the help pages on why and how are some answers deleted. But couldn't find any reason for it.

[image]

Help page says:
Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. **(My answer was accepted by the question asker, so this cannot be the reason!)** This includes answers that are:

> commentary on the question or other answers 
>   asking another, different question 
>   “thanks!” or “me too!” responses 
>   exact duplicates of other answers 
>   barely more than a link to an external site
>   not even a partial answer to the actual question

Answers can be deleted at any time by their authors, unless the answer has been accepted by the question asker. **(Again it was accepted, then why?)**

I couldn't find any other way to understand the reason, so i'm posting this as a question. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Perhaps @Bohemian can explain here why it was deleted?

Comment: Do you mean [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34582477/2055998)?

Comment: Nop.. not that answer.. it was a second answer to make it more simplified for the question seeker, which was a little bit different from my first answer, which was accepted and then deleted.

Comment: Here's [a screenshot of the deleted answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/57qAL.png) for those who cannot view it.

Comment: @KevinBrown without seeing the question, it seems that he's just repeating what another said.

Comment: Diamond moderator can delete the answer regardless of the "accept" status. However, I don't see any reason why it got deleted, given that the solution was different from Praveen's answer... unless the reason was hidden behind Praveen's revision. (I can't see the revision due to lack of rep to see deleted post).

Comment: @AndrewT. I just looked and Praveen's edit to the answer in question was merely formatting the code. But, unless I missed something, it looks like the two answers could have easily been edited into one which would help keep the site a bit cleaner. That would be my best guess on this one because it does seem different enough from the other answers.

Comment: Your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34581674/19679 was flagged as "not an answer", and deleted by a moderator as a result of that flag. Can't speak for the moderator involved, but I believe it may have been due to the "as praveen said" start to the answer. That may have made it seem like a "me too" response instead of an actual answer. I've undeleted it and pinged the moderator involved.

Comment: I [submitted a suggested edit which makes it clear that it is an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10768423), by linking to Praveen's original answer (which is what your `as praveen said` referred to), plus changed that text slightly to `As mentioned by`.

Comment: I got a question, why was this question downvoted?

Comment: And now there are *two* answers by @Sachin to the question :)

Comment: Sachin, now that your original answer has been un-deleted you should really merge your two answers into one. Even though the system allows you to post multiple answers it's not the normal way we do things on SO.

Comment: Thanks for helping all and I didn't add my other answer after my first answer was deleted. but i added my other answer because OP was having some difficulty in understanding the first answer and also was not available at that moment. So I added another answer which was pretty simple and improvised version for code, whereas my first answer was for least modification in OP's code. But I will keep this in mind to edit original answer instead of adding new unless it is necessary. Thanks all for helping :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sometimes answers are actually just comments on other answers. People might find an answer does what they need, except for a small tweak that isn't strictly relevant to the question. Things like

> jon's solution worked for me but I wanted to open it in a new tab so I wanted foo to be fully barred so I used `"foo=bar"` as a flag on it like this:
>
> ```
>  Someone else's code with a minor change
> ```

These aren't providing an answer per se, they merely say that another answer is correct and they add another note about it. In cases like this commenting or editing to include the note is more appropriate than a new answer.

Your answer began with "as Praveen said" which may have made it sound like one of these answers. Unfortunately sometimes people with limited time to judge see language that raises a flag and they act without fully assessing the situation. You can get caught in cases like this, but there's not much you could have done to avoid it apart from flagging an improper decision like this on meta (as you did).

Comment: ".. not much you could have done to avoid it apart from": well, perhaps from phrasing an answer like that.

Comment: ... only to get accused of taking credit for someone else's answer. Can't win.

Comment: @Sachin Glad to help! Also I'm not sure if Jongware was implying not to, but I definitely think you were right to note praveen's contribution. It's good to give others credit, it's just unfortunate it caused a mistake in your case.

Comment: hmm right @superbiasedman.. i was trying to do so..